# How to find processes that holds a file in C

Tags: c, linux

I want to find which processes holds some file in C code (Linux).

One way that comes to my mind is looking at `proc/<PID>/fd` for all running processes.
However, it would take so long time and because of sweeping all files under the `fd` files of all processes.

Could you give another method that is more lightweight?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does `lsof` computes its output ?

Comment: Its useful way, but I want to use the functionality within my application.

Comment: ` it would take so long time` Why ? Have you done some tests ?

Comment: I have not tested yet.
But the way I described incurs numerous access the filesystem even when almost of all processes is not relevant to the file. And accessing filesystem is done via kernel so that I predicted that looking at `/proc` leads to large overhead.
The application I am developing is too slow at this time and I will adopt more lightweight solution.

Comment: When I suggested `lsof` I meant: `did you read the source code ?`

Comment: the `/proc` structure is in memory, not on a disk, so searching it should be very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerating all the numerical pseudo-files under /proc, and then examining the fd/ directory for each one, is the standard way of doing this. It is the way that utilities like "lsof" are typically implemented. All this data is held in memory, so accessing it should be fast enough for most purposes.